# How to NTILE over distinct values in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that I'm trying to put together in Google BigQuery that would decile sales for each customer.  The problem I'm running into is that if a decile breaks at the point where many customers have the same sales value, they could end up in different deciles despite having the same sales.

For example, if there were twenty customers in total, and one spent $100, 18 spent $50, and one spent $25, the 18 customers who spent $50 will still be broken out across all the deciles due to equal groups being created, whereas in reality I would want them to be placed in the same decile.

The data that I'm using is obviously a bit more complex -- there are about 10 million customers, and the sales are deciled within a particular group to which each customer belongs.

Example code:

```
NTILE(10) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_group ORDER BY yearly_sales asc)  as current_sales_decile
```

The NTILE function works, but I just run into the problem described above and haven't figured out how to fix it.  Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the ntile yourself:

```
select ceiling(rank() over (partition by customer_group order by yearly_sales) * 10.0 /
               count(*) over (partition by customer_group)
              )
```

This gives you more control over how the tiles are formed.  In particular, all rows with the same value go in the same tile.